# How can I use the Windows 7 command prompt in fullscreen?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, fullscreen

I use some DOS applications in Windows 7.

Before Windows 7, I could press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the application in full screen, but with Windows 7 I can't do this anymore.

I get the message:

> This system does not support full screen mode

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 5):

I know that this isn't related to CMD, but if you really need to run dos applications in full screen, you can try setting up DosBox. http://www.dosbox.com/

Answer (score 4):

Full-screen mode for console applications (regardless of whether they're DOS programs or Windows console applications) isn't supported anymore with WDDM display drivers. You should still be able to go full-screen when using legacy drivers, although you then lose Aero and most of the hardware acceleration for display.

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap CMD in within [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/), you can make the windows as big as the screen if you wish, although there is no actual full screen mode.

Answer (score 0):

Vista and Windows 7 uses a very different video driver. It is infact very very much different from that of Windows XP. It improved performance but the down side is that it does not allow full screen console based applications to be launched.

Microsoft did launch a fix to downgrade the video driver to Windows XP but it is quite dangerous if things go wrong. So we might go for an alternative way. There are softwares which "emulate" the command prompt by software hence removing the need for windows command prompt completely. The user experience is not as good as the real one provides but it is still a decent solution to your problem.

Here is one:
http://blog.amolbhave.in/computers/full-screen-command-prompt-in-vista-and-windows-7/

Answer (score -3):

I presume that you run the app within XP mode.
If you disable "integration features" in the tools menu it should run just fine.