# Fullscreen DOS console on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, console

Is there a way to run a console program in fullscreen mode **on Windows 7**?

In previous versions of Windows, you could put the console into fullscreen mode.  This is not the same as simply maximizing the window -- it takes over the entire screen, showing only what you would have seen by running the program in DOS:

[image: adventure screenshot]

Comment: Also: [How can I use the Windows 7 command prompt in fullscreen?](http://superuser.com/questions/160134/how-can-i-use-the-windows-7-command-prompt-in-fullscreen), [How do I full-screen my CMD?](http://superuser.com/questions/285984/how-do-i-full-screen-my-cmd)

Answer (score 1):

Pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>⏎  Enter</kbd> should get you in and out of the fullscreen mode.

Comment: This gives the error message "This system does not support fullscreen mode."

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm using Windows 10, and it works for me (and also worked on older versions of Windows). Anyway, this has been marked as duplicate because other people have already asked and replied to this question. See the links left by @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007.

Comment: @screener Which build of Win 10 are you using?  It (still) doesn't work for me, even in Win10.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Build 9926 on a laptop with a simple onboard Intel graphics card. https://i.imgur.com/AO3YChu.png